# Server local error ASP.NET MVC app and SQL Server - >"A connection attempt failed..."

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a strange problem. I have a test server where I run my applications for people to test internally. It has a local instance of SQL Server Express, IIS with .NET 4.6 installed. To be clear firewall is completely turned off.

I've inherited some code that I can't run on the server. The application starts up fine but when I try to write or read from the DB I get the following:

> A connection attempt failed because the connection party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host failed to respond

What makes this issue weird is that I can locally connect to the database on the server. I can run the application on my local machine connecting to the database on the server. When I change the connection strings to something incorrect it throws this error.

So from what I can tell, the database is running fine. The application compiles fine on local machine and still connects to the database on the server. It's just when the application is hosted in IIS it's timing out connecting to the database.

The application is an ASP.NET MVC app.

If you can point me to any kind of reading or anything.

Comment: Without disclosing sensitive information - what is the connection string?

Comment: Agreed with Steve - most likely you need to tweak your connection string. It can be found in web.config file and here are some common examples https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/